# jquery select element with more then one id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to select an element, its id is assigned by mysql, it looks like this: `id="Monza ( Italien )5"` it works fine for other elements because there is only one name, but in this case it's the city name then the country name. I tried selecting like this `$('#Monza')` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use spaces or brackets, they are not a valid for ID attribute

> ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by
>   any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

and difference between HTML 4.01 and HTML5:

> The HTML 4.01 spec states that ID tokens must begin with a letter
>   ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).
>   For the class attribute, there is no such limitation. Classnames can
>   contain any character, and they don’t have to start with a letter to
>   be valid.
>
> HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the id attribute. The
>   only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are
>   that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty),
>   and that it can’t contain any space characters.

But you can try if you have no more choice:

```
$("div[id='Monza ( Italien )5']")
```

Unlike `$('#id')`, this will return multiple elements if you have multiple elements with the same id within your page

---

Seem like above selector is not working, you will need manually escape invalid characters here to make it works:

```
$("#Monza\\ \\(\\ Italien\\ \\)5")
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HLAzd/)</kbd>

Comment: HTML5 removes almost all of those restrictions: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use an attribute selector:

```
$('*[id="Monza ( Italien )5"]')
```

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) says that the `id` attribute cannot contain spaces, so I'd fix your HTML. Browsers might not cooperate if your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @Ian: Not really. It looks weird to me if there's no element.

Comment: Haha okay, I wasn't sure if I forgot something...I just had never used it before in this scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

Id is not supposed to have spaces between, check it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute). You can use some character like `_` to join the id parts.

*Change*

```
id="Monza ( Italien )5"
```

*To some thing like*

```
id="Monza_Italien_5"
```